# Recording Audacity Output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-recording, audacity

In Audacity, I'm selecting a short segment of audio and looping it for playback by holding down the shift key. Works great, and I love Audacity's fine-tuned selection and looping features. However, I would like to record the output with a second application (or another instance of Audacity) to create 3-minute "songs" of this looped audio, and am having no luck. I've tried Sound Recorder, and changing Pulse Audio Volume Control settings. Second instances of Audacity aren't working, either.

Comment: Providing your OS & release can be helpful.

Comment: You should have better luck with  copying multiples of your loop-selection to a new track and then simply save that track.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I got it to work by fiddling with the "Playback Device" dropdown in Audacity, and changing it to read "pulse." I'm not much of a computer person, despite being exclusively on linux for 10 years, so I don't really understand how it all works. But that made it possible to record the output with Sound Recorder, using the PAVC level control as a crude mixer to do a fade at the beginning and the end of the recording. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.